# Javascript Spacebar Event Handler - only works in Firefox

Tags: javascript, cross-browser, keypress

```
<script>

$(function(){

    $("#button-start").click(game.start);

    $(window).keypress(function(e) 
    {
        if (e.keyCode == 0) 
        {
            game.check(true);
        }
    });
});

</script>
```

This **only** captures the spacebar keypress event in **Firefox**. Does not work in IE or Chrome.

How do I modify this to make it work for all browsers?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery normilised the key codes under [`which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) event property. Spacebar has code `32`:

```
$(window).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 32) {
        game.check(true);
    }
});
```

You can use `$(document)` instead to be more browser compatible.

Comment: @CODe Have you tried to use `$("body")` or `$(document)` instead of `$(window)`?

Comment: Son of a... <code>$(document)</code> did it. Mention that in your answer and I'll accept. Thanks!